# Как попарно сложить целые числа из множества?

Tags: java, set, int

Допустим, у меня есть множество:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(1);
        set.add(2);
        set.add(3);
        set.add(4);
        set.add(5);
        set.add(6);
        set.add(7);
        set.add(8);
```

как попарно сложить числа до тех пор, пока не останется одно число?
Например:

> [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
> [3 7 11 15]
> [10 26]
> [36]

Пожалуйста, подскажите, сломала всю голову.

Comment: зачем так усложнять, если от перемены мест слагаемых сумма не меняется (особенно с учетом того, что хешсет сам определяет порядок элементов)? просто сложите все числа: int result = set.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();

Comment: @Дмитрий, если хешсет сам определяет порядок элементов, а для хранения промежуточных сумм предполагается использовать именно его, результаты могут быть непредсказуемы :)

Comment: @Nowhere Man результат будет всегда одинаковый. какая разница между 2+3+4+5, 3+4+2+5, (3+5)+(2+4)? все равно в итоге 14

Comment: 2 + 5 == 3 + 4 -- если промежуточные суммы добавлять в хешсет, то дубликаты будут игнорироваться и добавится только одна семерка, см. мой ответ

Comment: @Nowhere Man смотрю ответ. и снова прихожу к выводу, что это все бессмысленно. если вам нужен промежуточный результат попарных вычислений, то ваш фокус провалился в момент, когда вы "создали упорядоченный список". откуда вы знаете порядок, в котором автор вопроса добавлял числа, если там хешсет? а если вам нужен только конечный результат, то он , как не крути, 36 и все ваши танцы с бубном бесполезны

Comment: Я показал пример с отсортированным сетом на входе (не используя `List`), чтобы гарантировать желаемый конечный результат.

Comment: @Nowhere Man проблема в том, что у автора вопроса хешсет. если исходить из возможности изменения исходных данных, то любую задачу можно адаптировать под любое решение. а если исходить из условий задачи, то все сводится исключительно к расчету суммы чисел, а представить другое решение не представляется возможным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, данная задача на написание рекурсивной функции, которая выводила бы промежуточные суммы пар.

Также можно предположить, что данную задачу следует решать при помощи итераторов, а не доступа через индексы.

```java
public static Set<Integer> sumPairs(Set<Integer> set) {
    System.out.println(set);
    if (set.size() < 2) {
        return set;
    }
    Set<Integer> pairs = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (Iterator<Integer> it = set.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Integer p1 = it.next();
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            p1 += it.next();
        }
        pairs.add(p1);
    }
    return sumPairs(pairs);
}
```

Тест:

```java
System.out.println("Сумма: " + sumPairs(new TreeSet<>(Set.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))));
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 7, 11, 15]
[10, 26]
[36]
Сумма: [36]
```

Следует заметить, что в общем случае `HashSet` не гарантирует порядок элементов, и это может привести в некоторых случаях к "странным" результатам, поскольку промежуточные суммы будут дублироваться, например:

```
System.out.println("Сумма: " + sumPairs(Set.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)));

[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3]  // 4 + 5 == 8 + 1 - только одна девятка!
[9, 13, 5]
[22, 5]
[27]
Сумма: [27]

[2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
[3, 15, 11, 7]           // 3 + 15 == 11 + 7
[18]
Сумма: [18]

[1, 8, 2, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3]
[9]
Сумма: [9]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все подробно описали.

Comment: да-да, делаю, еще раз благодарю!;)
Подскажите, если в HashSet у меня имеются пары "ключ/значение".
И есть такая задача:
Заполнить HashMap 10 объектами <Integer, String>. Найти строки, у которых ключ > 5.
Если ключ = 0, вывести строки через запятую. Перемножить все ключи, где длина строки > 5.
и И вот вопрос: как же тогда использовать HashMap, если значения в нем не дублируются? Может есть какая-то альтернатива?

Comment: @Nowere Man это про условие с нулями.
Что, если имеется несколько ключей со значением '0'?

Comment: В хеш-таблице _ключи_ уникальны (так что может быть только один 0), а значения вполне могут дублироваться.

Answer (score 0):

Создаем упорядоченный список `list` на основе вашего `set`, зацикливаемся до тех пор, пока в `list` более 1 элемента. Во внутреннем цикле `for` попарно складываем элементы. Если в `list` нечетное число элементов, то в последней итерации цикла в качестве второго слагаемого берем число `0`:

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
System.out.println(list);
while (list.size() > 1) {
    List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += 2) {
        int a = list.get(i);
        int b = i + 1 < list.size() ? list.get(i + 1) : 0;
        newList.add(a + b);
    }
    list = newList;
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

На выходе:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 7, 11, 15]
[10, 26]
[36]
```

Comment: Отличный подход! Благодарю!